# In “Why do you think this is?” is the verb “to be” a linking verb or a stative verb?

Tags: be, stative-verbs, linking-verbs

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj3iNxZ8Dww) clip, you can hear the following question:

> Recent polls have shown a fifth of Americans can’t locate the US on a world map. Why do you think **this is**?

It’s not clear to me if the clause “This is” leaves out something, e.g. “This is *like that*”, “This is *true*” and so on, or if, on the contrary, the verb “to be” is used here with a full stative meaning, as if it meant “This *exists*“.

Moreover, is this usage of the verb “to be” linked to questions such as that I gave as an example, or can it also be used in affirmative sentences?

Comment: I'm having difficulty with your final paragraph.

Comment: @EuanM I’ll try to explain myself better. I would like to know if you can use “This is” as it appears in my example in an affirmative sentence such as the following: “_This is_ because the American people have no maps”. Is this latter usage correct?

Comment: You certainly can use *this is* in an affirmative statement. Bear in mind *that* is often precisely equivalent to *this* in contexts where you're referencing something that was/is in the immediate vicinity. Such as the last statement made by someone else, with which you might reasonably express complete agreement by saying ***That is true***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ordinary 'linking verb' or *copula*, and the copula *is* stative—it's practically the paradigmatic stative.

As for the construction, work back from the desired answer. *Why* is an interrogative pro-form standing for an adverbial of purpose, so it can act as a predicate complement:

> I think this is *because X*
>   ↓ *replace the adverbial with its interrogative pro-form*
>   I think this is *why*.
>   ↓ *move the interrogative pro-form to the front and invert the verb and subject with* do-support
>   Why do you think this is _? . . . *the _ marks the 'gap' or 'trace'*

Comment: I think that your explanation hits the nail on the head. So, this kind of questions sort of echoes a possible answer by using exactly the same construction.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the verb *to be* has a 'stative' quality.

One could have said *Why do you think this is so?* But in the absence of *so* I find it unnecessary to re-instate it in brackets for the purpose of parsing the sentence.

Indeed I see no reason why it cannot similarly be used in the affirmative, for example:

*My neighbours have gone to Spain, and I know exactly why that is.*

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially short for

"*Why do you think [that] this [fact] is [true]?*"

or

"*Why do you think [that] this [fact that I have just stated] is [true]?*"

So the final "*this is*" is being used in a stative sense - it is describing a state of being, and not an action.  But it's also a linking verb, linking "*this*" to its *truthiness*.

Comment: *Why do you think this is [so]?*

Comment: @bib Why are you unaware of the traditional use in English of *[* and *]* ?

Comment: @bib Unless you are referring to *truthiness*, in which case, why are you unaware of Steven Colbert and the emergence of *truthiness* from popular culture, and its adoption into usage from there?

Comment: This is an artifact of the markup language. I was trying to say *Why do you think this is (so)?* using standard brackets, but the markup changed it to the Stack Overflow link. I was offering what WS2 discussed shortly thereafter - the pronoun *so* as the predicate nominative of *is*.

Comment: lol!  Well, that certainly changes the meaning of your comment!

Comment: Tbh, I'd then just want to expand "Why is this so?" into "Why is this as it is?"

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding that toe-curling youtube clip, it's reasonably rare for "why do you think this is?", "why is this?" or "why is it so?" to literally be a question to another person.  In a lot of English speech it is used rhetorically, and the questioner (a reporter, a panellist, or a college lecturer, say) will go on to answer it themselves.